# Agendador não carrega no início da aplicação

Tags: jboss, ejb

Estou tentando criar um agendador simples de tarefas utilizando `EJB`, porém como resultado ele não está carregando no início da aplicação, que seria através da anotação `@Startup`. Utilizo `jdk 1.8 wildFly 11.0`.

Além disso, no console do `wildFly`  não aparece nenhum erro, nem warning. Eu não sei o que pode estar acontecendo. Alguém poderia me ajudar? Ou teria um dica do que poderia ser? Teria alguma configuração no  wildFly?

Minha classe Agendador.java

```
import javax.ejb.Schedule;

import javax.ejb.Singleton;

import javax.ejb.Startup;


@Singleton

@Startup

public class Agendador {

    @Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*", second = "*/10", persistent = false)
    void agendado() {
        System.out.println("verificando serviço externo periodicamente");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O seu Bean está sendo carregado mas só vai iniciar após o tempo configurado.

Você pode confirmar isso acrescentando a Anotação @PostConstruct:

```
package br.com.exemplo.agendador.servico;

import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;

@Singleton
@Startup
public class Agendador {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Agendador.class.getName());

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        LOG.info("inicializado");
    }

    @Schedule(second = "*/10", minute = "*", hour = "*", persistent = false)
    public void agendado() {
        LOG.info("verificando serviço externo periodicamente");
    }

}
```